# What happened to Edit.MoveLineUp/Down in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2010 you can assign keyboard shortcuts for moving lines up and down.

[image: Visual Studio 2010]

I can't find these commands in 2012.

[image: Visual Studio 2012]

Have they been renamed or removed? Is there any way, *out-of-the-box*, to move lines using <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>? (I'm not buying ReSharper.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This command is a part of **Productivity Power Tools**.

The 2012 version was released in November 2012.  You can find it here:

[Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/11/07/productivity-power-tools-2012.aspx)

Comment: This feature is now standard starting with VS2013 ([click](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2013/07/01/visual-studio-2013-preview-moving-lines-of-code.aspx]))

Comment: I wish there was something equivalent for SQL Server Management Studio... I miss this function!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing happened to it, these commands don't exist in VS2010 either.  Check what add-ins you've got installed.

Not sure what it does, but consider Edit.ScrollLineUp/Down.  Default binding is Ctrl+Up/Down arrow.

Comment: Well, pooey. Productivity Power Tools must create those commands. I thought it only assigned them keyboard shortcuts.